# How to determine the direction of a Linked List

Tags: java, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I have to make a linked list that adds to itself to the left so I'm thinking it's something like this where the boxes are nodes and the arrow is the link:

```
tail [] <- [] <- [] <- ... [] head
```

But how do you determine the direction of the linked list when you are adding the second node?
How do you know which side it's going to be placed on?

```
2nd?  1st  2nd?
 []   []   []
```

For example this code: head = new IntNode(5,head)
would add to the right if the linked list is like this:

```
         head         tail
    [] -> [] -> [] -> []
```

But that's only when adding to an already made list with that format, so which side will it start from when creating a new linked list?

Comment: This is a bit like asking whether a family tree goes downwards or upwards. Traditionally it is drawn with parents above children, but it doesn't have to be: draw it however you like, as long as the structure is the same. Linked lists are, I suppose, usually drawn with head on the left and tail on the right; but that's only because most languages read from left to right. It's not an intrinsic property of a linked list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, there is no `left` and `right` with linked lists.

That direction is just used for convenient graphical representation since we can easily picture it. You can technically draw a linked list sideways, up to down, down to up, left to right, doesn't really matter.

All linked lists have is a **single direction from head to tail**. Or in case of doubly linked lists, a **bi-direction from head to tail and from tail to head**.

I guess you could technically make a doubly linked list where all `"left"` or `"prev"` pointers are `null` to make it seem like it goes right. Or make all of its `"right"` or `"next"` pointers `null` and make it seem like it goes left. In either case, such direction has no actual meaning.

In memory, linked list node's value of `Node.next` just contains a memory address of the next node. That memory location doesn't have to physically be right next to the node. Technically, linked list pointers can zig-zag all over memory, connecting blocks wherever the OS and underlying system decided to allocate memory for them. There is no "*natural*" order like we are used to in real life, **just sequence of pointers from head to tail**

For example, these two lists are equivalent as far as the computer is concerned. I just drew them in different directions :)

[image: linked lists]

Comment: Lol yea, a linked list's direction should only determined by its head to tail direction. Thanks i should of thought about it more, the answer is like right in front of me.